# Installing google map on Ionic 2 shows no dependencies

Tags: google-maps, ionic2

When I installing Google map via typings install dt~google.maps --global , is shows 'no dependencies'. How I can solve this. Thank you.

Comment: you do not need typings just follow the [link](http://www.joshmorony.com/creating-an-advanced-google-maps-component-in-ionic-2/) tutorial

Comment: Typings aren't necessary but they are essential for proper ts development. What kind of a suggestion is this